# Implementing Wallet Extension for iOS in React Native

Tags: swift, react-native, applepay, apple-wallet, walletextension

i hope my question is not out of the box, but the problem is...i need to implement ios wallet extension in react native app.

There is not so much information, i read official apple docs where are some informations about flow, but honestly it is not giving required insight how to do it with React Native. Only one stuff that brought a little bit of information about some steps is documentation from [Mea docs](https://developer.meawallet.com/mpp/react-native/wallet-extensions-guide/), but you need to use Mea service that i do not use on project.

I need to implement this wallet extension for iOS in react native app with both **IssuerUIExtension** and **IssuerNonUIExtension.** Im not so skilled in native iOS code, but i tried to implement this UI and NonUIExtensions as modules, but then it wont register. I managed to display my app as recommended in apple wallet app using native IssuerNonUIExtension class in ios native code, but i cant progress to get passes and create UIExtension.

This stuffs should be done somehow through RN and also this IssuerNonUIExtension, but i do not have idea how to do that and i could not find no information how i could progress with that. Does someone have experience with Wallet Extension for iOS in React Native? Could you give me some hint or help how to progress with that? Thank you

I could not find any informations regarding implementation for wallet extension through React Native on ios.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it helps you but there's no significant difference in implementation between wallet extensions and other iOS extensions. The only differences are entitlements & superclasses  (e.g `PKIssuerProvisioningExtensionHandler / PKIssuerProvisioningExtensionAuthorizationProviding` ) so if you find how to implement any other iOS extension in React Native it shouldn't be that different for the wallet extensions.

> but i tried to implement this UI and NonUIExtensions as modules, but then it wont register.

I am not sure if you've got required entitlements from Apple because if you haven't then the registration problem might be caused by this.